# Is this $\binom{n}{p}$ for $p>n$ make a sense in mathematics or it is $0$ by convention?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, definition, convention

It is well known that gamma function is not defined at negative integers , but my question is to know how i take the value of   $\binom{n}{p}$ for  $p>n$ then is this  make a sense or it is  $0$ by convention ?

Comment: I believe it is $0$ by convention. At least that is what Sheldon Ross’s Probability textbook states.

Comment: If $p > n$, how many ways are there to choose $p$ distinct objects from a set of $n$ distinct objects?

Comment: in my opinion is 0 (nothing ) , the problem is in the definition of Gamma function at negative integers, I understand you you mean in the view of probability that is 0, many people took it as convention

Comment: I think there is a very general principle in mathematics: whenever something is defined by convention, it is because of the convention is the thing that makes the most sense. If no choice would makes any more sense than the other (e.g. when choosing a value for 0/0) there will be no convention. In all the situation where there are conventions (e.g. sum of zero terms has value 0 but product of zero terms has value 1) it is quite easy to understand why it is the most sensible convention. Same here. So 'is it a convention or does it make sense' is a false dichotomy. The answer is often 'both'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $\binom{n}{p}$ as the number of subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ having exactly $p$ elements.

Then it makes mathematical sense to say that $\binom{n}{p}=0$ if $p>n$.
Of course, if you choose this definition then you have to prove that $\binom{n}{p} = \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$ for all $p, n \in \mathbb N$ such that $p \leq n$.

Answer (score 4):

> A common definition of the binomial coefficient with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and integer values $p$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{\alpha}{p}=
> \begin{cases}
>   \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-p+1)}{p!}&p\geq 0\\
>   0&p<0
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> From this we conclude $\binom{n}{p}=0$ if $p>n \ \ (n,p\in\mathbb{N})$.

*Hint:* The chapter 5 *[Binomial coefficients](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik provides a thorough introduction. The formula above is stated as (5.1).

Comment: +1 This is the definition that arises naturally from the binomial series expansion

Comment: @MarkS.: Correct. One of the main reasons for this definition, i think. Thanks for the credit.

Answer (score 3):

If you directly define $\binom{n}{p}$ as $\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(n-p+1)}$ and recall that $\Gamma(x)$ ha simple poles at $0,-1,-2,\ldots$, it is no wonder that $\binom{n}{p}=0$ for $p,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p>n$. It is usually introduced by convention, but it is also the unique convention which agrees with the analytic continuation of the binomial coefficients through the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Slick answer , I up vote to this answer